# Rendering difference in a very basic html

Tags: html, firefox, google-chrome

I am executing the following `html` on `FF5`,`Chrome10`, `IE9`
The text is wrapped into two lines in FF5, where as in Chrome and IE, the td is streched to keep it in one line.

I am unable to debug this:

```
 <table width="80%">
 <tbody>
 <tr>
 <td width="5%" align="center" style="font-size:10px" class="filename">2</td>
 <td width="50%" style="display:block">
 D:/C_daive/Dpcnet/nbndinh/Denktpp/Nbndinh/MyjilenTpTentMybpp//bttic/ppcpden/jm_nubncaiptipn_ppl/jm_nubncaiptipn_ppl_updbte_nubncaiptipn_cpunt.c
 </td>  
 <td width="25%" align="center" style="font-size:10px" class="filename">Combo</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

How can I get the wrapping working on Chrome and IE

Comment: so what do you want? to make it look like one line or split?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `word-wrap` in css

```
<table width="80%">
 <tbody>
 <tr>
 <td width="5%" align="center" style="font-size:10px" class="filename">2</td>
 <td width="50%" style="display:block; word-wrap: break-word;">
 D:/C_daive/Dpcnet/nbndinh/Denktpp/Nbndinh/MyjilenTpTentMybpp//bttic/ppcpden/jm_nubncaiptipn_ppl/jm_nubncaiptipn_ppl_updbte_nubncaiptipn_cpunt.c
 </td>  
 <td width="25%" align="center" style="font-size:10px" class="filename">Combo</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

ref: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/word-wrap-force-text-to-wrap

Comment: Thank you for the timely help. It saved tons of time. I am in a process of migrating a site built on FF to work with IE and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `word-wrap: break-word;` after `display:block;`.

By the way, you should perhaps consider putting your css in a separate stylesheet. ([Why inline css and javascript is a bad thing.](http://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/))